# How can I store a process?

Tags: java, selenium

I have a linked list being created and consider each element of the list as an action. For example, element 1 is clicking the button, element 2 is selecting something in the dropdown. The elements are composed of selenium actions.

How can I store this linked list tho? I want this action to happen again everytime (I am a web tester trying to use selenium). One way is for action like clicking a button, write down "click button" on a .txt file and read that .txt file.

Is there a better method? I find my current method VERY dirty and has a lot of if-else statements

For example

```
if ("click button"){

//selenium code for clicking button

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tool like [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm) to do the heavy lifting for you. If you can write your test descriptions in the Gherkin language (using GIVEN - WHEN - THEN sections) then Cucumber can route each phrase to a method (aka Step Definition) via an annotation (or using a lambda syntax in Java8). The method can then contain your Selenium test code.

Answer (score 1):

How about putting the actions in a single method that you can call everytime

```
public void performActions(){
    clickButtonMethod(btnSelector)
    selectSomethingInDropdown(somethingSelector)
}
```

With this im trying to refer to the Page Object design pattern
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern

With this you can call these methods from all test cases that require it